# I get the error: "Cannot read property 'g-recaptcha-response' of undefined" when trying to use reCAPTCHA in node

Tags: javascript, node.js

When submiting my form with the reCAPTCHA element in it i get this error: Cannot read property 'g-recaptcha-response' of undefined

This is my code for reciving the reCAPTCHA

```
app.post('/captcha', function(req, res) {
  console.log("BRUH")
  if(req.body['g-recaptcha-response'] === undefined || req.body['g-recaptcha-response'] === '' || req.body['g-recaptcha-response'] === null)
  {
    return res.json({"responseError" : "Please select captcha first"});
  }
  const secretKey = "6Lez4cEUAAAAAHxMs9ChAG9CfU4Piu23ql2PYV2t";

  const verificationURL = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" + secretKey + "&response=" + req.body['g-recaptcha-response'] + "&remoteip=" + req.connection.remoteAddress;

  request(verificationURL,function(error,response,body) {
    body = JSON.parse(body);

    if(body.success !== undefined && !body.success) {
      return res.json({"responseError" : "Failed captcha verification"});
      console.log("error");
    }
    res.json({"responseSuccess" : "Sucess"});
    console.log("succes");
  });
});
```

Comment: Seems like the `req.body` is `undefined`. Aren't you supposed to read `g-recaptcha-response` from `res.body` instead of `req.body`?

Comment: @ajobi Hmm didn't seem like that worked, thanks for the answer tho :)